# Can't get onActivityResult on the calling activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, startactivityforresult

I'm trying to get a photo from the Gallery using `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, what I'm trying to do is to call `startActivityForResult` like the normal way:

```
// at CallerActivity
private View.OnClickListener onChoosingGallery = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, MY_REQUEST_CODE_PICK_GALLERY);
    }
};
```

after the call the gallery opens and I can choose an image successfully then it closes when choosing the image "as regular" but after that, I'm not getting a call to `onActivityResult()` on my activity(let's call it `CallerActivity`).
this is my first scenario which I'm getting when starting `CallerActivity` using the regular way after receivg a Broadcast receiver:

```
    broadCast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CallerActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
```

and my second scenario is when calling the `CallerActivity` using `startActivityForResult()`:

```
    broadCast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CallerActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, MY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    };
```

in that case I'm getting `onActivityResult()` from Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT on the `MainActivity` directly despite I didn't call `startActivityForResult()` from it, it just passes the `CallerActivity` and goes directly to the activity which called the `CallerActivity` which is `MainActivity`, and when check the `resultIntent` at `onActivityResult()` it is not coming from `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` but it comes from `CallerActivity` with `resultCode' equals 'Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`.

---

I found a lot of related problems on SO, but no one of them is actually my case, I didn't define `CallerActivity` as `singleInstance` in the **manifest.xml** and I didn't set `android:noHistory="true"` also. Just normal declaration for the activity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Views.Activities.CallerActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

---

Worth to mention that I'm using the same logic somewhere else in another activity and it works perfectly, Any idea about what would be my problem or even how to put a clue on the reason for such behavior ?

Comment: Try to start CallerActivity in 'the normal way'. Without a broadcast receiver. Just form the main activity.

Comment: `and when check the resultIntent at onActivityResult() it is not coming from Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT but it comes from CallerActivity with resultCode' equals 'Activity.RESULT_CANCELED.` My god. Did tell that right away! Your CallerActivity is crashing or so. It crashes in onActivityResult. Remove all code there.

Comment: No, I'm debugging the app it's not even going there, and I can't start the Activity from outside BC as it has to start according to some condition

Comment: That does not matter. You could do the test i proposed. `BC` ???

Comment: I will do a test and tell you , BC is for Broadcast Receiver :D

Comment: `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` Test without.